# Cooking (not baking) adjustments for altitude

Tags: high-altitude

I currently live at altitude (5,280 ft/1609 m), but I grew up and learned to cook at sea level, so my recipes are written with sea level temperatures and cooking times in mind. This isn't particularly *high* altitude -- you definitely don't need to do the crazy stuff necessary for 10,000 ft -- but it starts to get noticeable here. Water boils at about 200 degrees instead of 212, for example, which simplifies making certain kinds of tea. You do need to do slight adjustments when baking or making griddlecakes/pancakes.

I have a specific problem, where when I make bean soups using the same recipes I used at sea level, I find that I need to greatly extend the cooking time in order to get the beans to the correct consistency and not crunchy. Short of using a pressure cooker, I'm wondering if there are specific ways I need to change my technique or adjust the recipe to deal with altitude.

A specific recipe I've made at both altitudes goes like this:

- soak dry beans
- drain beans and put in a soup pot along with a ham hock and 7 cups cold water
- bring to boil, reduce heat, simmer until beans are tender

There are additional steps, but this is where things are getting tricksy. The recipe I'm following suggests that you simmer approximately 1.25 hours -- and this is just about accurate for sea level. Following the same steps, at altitude, however, the beans are crunchy and *not* tender at all at this same point in time. I made this soup a few days ago and ended up having to simmer for nearly double the time (2h 20m roughly) in order to get the beans to the desired consistency. Even though there's 30 minutes of additional simmering after the addition of carrots, celery, onion, garlic, potatoes, the recipe as originally written leaves the beans under-done and unpleasantly firm or crunchy.

Other than doubling the cooking time, are there other ways to adjust this recipe so that the beans get tender? I don't have a pressure cooker and really am not looking to increase my collection of kitchen gadgetry. Otherwise, will increasing temperature help? For example, cooking at a low boil rather than a simmer? I don't think the addition of salt will help since depressing the boiling point *further* doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: Unfortunately most of the high altitude cooking guidance is baking focused -- which makes sense because that gets very complicated. :(

Comment: Given that you're living 1.6km up, I'd suggest that getting a pressure cooker would be a very good investment for you.

Comment: It won’t help, but since you mentioned it, salt *increases* the boiling point.

Comment: Right, it lowers the specific heat, but increases the boiling point. Had a moment of stupid there. Either way you need a _lot_ of salt to make a noticeable difference, and there's salt in the ham hocks anyway.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't tried this specifically at altitude, but baking soda does wonders for softening stubborn beans in general. Serious Eats recommends [soaking them in it](https://www.seriouseats.com/baking-soda-brine-for-beans-5217841); I've had success with adding a pinch to the cooking water (not so much that it damages the flavor!). On the flip side, make sure you're not adding acidic ingredients like tomatoes, which lengthen the cooking time

Comment: The recipe is literally as written. Ham hock + beans soaked overnight + cold water. The only "unwritten" ingredient here might be some extra salt courtesy of the ham -- no acid I'm aware of. Are you suggesting adding baking soda during the bean soaking, or during the simmering?

Comment: Either way! I add baking soda during the simmering, and Serious Eats recommends during the soaking.

Comment: Soaking the beans in baking soda definitely helps to soften them. You may have to play around with different amounts of baking soda and soaking time to get them to the desired consistency, though. Too much and they get mushy. (As well as getting a slightly chalky taste.) If done properly it shouldn't have any impact on the taste.